# mouseover to display the data

Tags: javascript, mouseover

The manager's first name is displayed on the page.  I want to display the manager's full name when hovering over the 'eye' icon.  Is there a JavaScript that can be used to do this?  Below is my codes.  Thanks

```
<td><span class="eye"></span><s:property value="managerfullname" /></td>
```

Comment: yes there is. but what have you tried so far?

Comment: What manager? What eye icon? That's not code, it's just a block of HTML. What have you tried, etc,etc

Comment: `.eye:hover ~ s:property {display:block}`

Comment: If I'm reading Struts properties properly, you can just add a title attribute to your span element and add your property value into the title (quotes and all): `<span class="eye" title="<s:property value="managerfullname" />"></span>`

Comment: Thanks Chris.  It works perfectly!!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JS use the `data-*` attribute with the `:after` pseudo and `:hover`

```css
[data-surname]:hover:after{
  content: " " attr(data-surname);
}
```

```html
<span data-surname="C. Buljan">Roko</span>
```

If you want it "pop-up" than

```css
[data-surname]{
  position:relative;
}
[data-surname]:hover:after{
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  top: 100%;
  left:0;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  content: attr(data-surname);
}
```

```html
<span data-surname="Roko C. Buljan">Roko</span>
```